# How do I configure nmap to verify my firewall is performing stateful packet inspection?

Tags: network, firewalls, audit

As part of a compliance audit, I need to run a routine scan that verifies that our firewalls are performing stateful packet inspection on incoming packets. I have a dedicated server outside our network, on which I can run nmap or whatever software I need to, and scan the external port of our firewall.

The compliance audit manual says I should "run NMAP on all TCP ports with “syn reset” or ”syn ack” bits set", and that a response means 'packets are being allowed through even if they're not part of a previously established session'

What are the nmap switches I need to scan a range of IP addresses - in this case a single /28 subnet - and report on which ports are open and whether the firewall is performing SPI?

Server is Windows 2008; nmap version 5.21 is installed and working.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The flag for SYN ACK scans is `-sA`. scanning all ports is `-p-` `192.168.0.0/28` will scan for the obvious subnet. You may want `-vv` to see more details

The following command:

```
nmap -sA -p- 192.168.0.0/28 -vv
```

should work.

Comment: You might want to disable ping discovery (`-Pn`) as well.

Answer (score 2):

The option `-sA` is a good approach for this. Though the better way to know, if your firewall it's performing stateless or statefull filtering, is by seeing the conf file or the configuration in general.

A way to achieve this with nmap would be this: First do a `-sS` (syn scan) scan on all ports and see what ports are filtered. Then perform an `-sA` (ack scan) scan and if the same ports received the result unfiltered it's most likely your firewall not performing statefull filter.

Answer (score 1):

This is all, more or less, in the nmap man page. Read about -sA and --scanflags and you should be able to figure it out.

Perhaps I was too brief here.  Apologies.

Along with what was in the second answer you can use the --scanflags argument to set whatever flags you want - for "syn reset" you would use `--scanflags RSTSYN`.  If you also specify -sS (to do a "syn scan") you'll have the responses interpreted correctly, with nmap interpreting no response as a closed port, which I think is what you want.